# UIImage never frees memory (memory leak?)

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiimage, apple-vision

So long as I retain a reference to the `UIImage` passed as an argument to either of these functions, the memory increase caused by each image-related operation remains. If I call these functions repeatedly (each time with a different instance of `UIImage`) the memory usage increases until the app crashes.

example1:

```
static func memoryNotReleasedExample(image: UIImage) {
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return }
    let imageTranslationRequest = VNTranslationalImageRegistrationRequest(targetedCGImage: cgImage)
}
```

example2:

```
static func memoryNotReleasedExample2(image: UIImage) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
    guard let copy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Why does this happen? Is it a bug? Is there a way to forcefully free the memory?